# Reduce array in javascript based on two conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, reduce

Lets say we have an array of object like:

```
[ 
    { id: 1, time: "2021-05-02 10:12:45.123" },
    { id: 1, time: "2021-05-02 11:12:45.123" },
    { id: 1, time: "2021-05-02 12:12:45.123" },
    { id: 2, time: "2021-05-02 05:12:45.123" },
    { id: 1, time: "2021-05-01 12:12:45.123" },
    { id: 2, time: "2021-05-01 05:12:45.123" },
    { id: 2, time: "2021-05-01 04:12:45.123" },
    { id: 3, time: "2021-05-01 10:12:45.123" },
]
```

So my purpose is to reduce the array in javascript so the result to be -> for every Id for every day to have the latest time like:

```
[ 
    { id: 1, time: "2021-05-02 12:12:45.123" },
    { id: 2, time: "2021-05-02 05:12:45.123" },
    { id: 1, time: "2021-05-01 12:12:45.123" },
    { id: 2, time: "2021-05-01 05:12:45.123" },
    { id: 3, time: "2021-05-01 10:12:45.123" },
]
```

Please can you help with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve the result using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, time: "2021-05-02 10:12:45.123" },
  { id: 1, time: "2021-05-02 11:12:45.123" },
  { id: 1, time: "2021-05-02 12:12:45.123" },
  { id: 2, time: "2021-05-02 05:12:45.123" },
  { id: 1, time: "2021-05-01 12:12:45.123" },
  { id: 2, time: "2021-05-01 05:12:45.123" },
  { id: 2, time: "2021-05-01 04:12:45.123" },
  { id: 3, time: "2021-05-01 10:12:45.123" },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc.length && acc[acc.length - 1].id === curr.id) {
    if (new Date(acc[acc.length - 1].time) < new Date(curr.time)) {
      acc[acc.length - 1] = { ...acc[acc.length - 1], ...curr };
    }
  } else acc.push(curr);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```